# covington with lines as arguments of enclosing macro

Tags: pdftex, covington

I need some glosses and use [covington.sty](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/covington/covington.sty) for that (if you can solve my problem with [another package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77937/numbered-examples-in-linguistics-that-i-can-refer-back-to/77941#77941) I don't mind, I'd need to refactor everything for the solution, anyway). `\gll` expects two lines: the text to be glossed (`Hallo Welt` in the example) and the gloss of the text (`Hello World` in the example). Now I want a command `\autogloss` that automatically writes the second line for me. That is, the commands `\hello{} \world{}` that are common to both lines of `\gll` become the first argument of `\autogloss`. However, this fails to compile with `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`.

I guessed it might be because the argument is not expanded, though then it should still have glossed it (just not properly) - and no amount of `\expandafter` seems to work.

I get the same message when I put a `%` at the ends of the lines of the working example so I thought the solution from [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169740/covington-example-in-footnote/169744#169744) might work, but it doesn't seem to (but maybe I did something wrong there).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{covington}

\newcounter{@language}
\setcounter{@language}{0}
\def\english{\setcounter{@language}{0}}
\def\german{\setcounter{@language}{1}}

\newcommand\hello{\ifnumcomp{\value{@language}}{=}{0}{Hello}{Hallo}}
\newcommand\world{\ifnumcomp{\value{@language}}{=}{0}{World}{Welt}}

\newcommand\autogloss[2]{%
    \gll \german{}#1
    \english{}#1
    \glt `#2'
    \glend
}

\begin{document}
\begin{examples}
\item this one works:
    \gll \german{}\hello{} \world{}
    \english{}\hello{} \world{}
    \glt `Hello World.'
    \glend
\item this one doesn't: % comment next line to compile.
    \autogloss{\hello{} \world{}}{`Hello World.'}
\end{examples}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `gb4e`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\newcounter{@language}
\setcounter{@language}{0}
\def\english{\setcounter{@language}{0}}
\def\german{\setcounter{@language}{1}}

\newcommand\hello{\ifnumcomp{\value{@language}}{=}{0}{Hello}{Hallo}}
\newcommand\world{\ifnumcomp{\value{@language}}{=}{0}{World}{Welt}}

\newcommand\autogloss[2]{%
    \gll \german{}#1\\
    \english{}#1\\
    \glt `#2'
}

\let\eachwordone=\it

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex this one works:
    \gll \german{}\hello{} \world{}\\
    \english{}\hello{} \world{}\\
    \glt `Hello World.'
\ex this one does, as well:
    \autogloss{\hello{} \world{}}{Hello World.}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: That works in the MWE, but in the real document I get `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]` which can be reproduced in the MWE by adding `\usepackage{xstring}` **after** `\usepackage{gb4e}`, so I'll have to put it before.

Comment: @user66554 Just load `xstring` *before* `gb4e`.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that.

Comment: Generally, `gb4e` should be loaded as late as possible in the loading order.